# Bootstrap col-12 on small screens and fixed length on larger screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I found this sidebar code snippet, how do I change it so that the sidebar stacks on top on small screens and have a fixed width or max width on large screens. I have tried limiting the aside element with max-width but it is not working.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row wrapper min-vh-100 flex-column flex-sm-row">
                <aside class="col-12 col-sm-2 p-0 bg-dark flex-shrink-1">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark align-items-start flex-sm-column flex-row">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-fw"></i> Brand</a>
                        <a href class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sidebar">
                            <ul class="flex-column navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="">Link</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0 dropdown-toggle text-nowrap" href="#m1" data-parent="#navbar1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#m1" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="fa fa-address-card-o fa-fw"></i> <span class=""> Link</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="m1">
                                        <ul class="flex-column nav">
                                            <a class="nav-link px-0 text-truncate" href="#">Sub</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link px-0 text-truncate" href="#">Sub longer</a>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> <span class="">Link</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-fw"></i> <span class="">Link</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </aside>
                <main class="col bg-faded py-3">
                    <h2>Main</h2>
                    <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics, raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
                    <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It is working as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: is there any css for this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  
  aside {
    width: 200px !important;
   }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- your code -->

<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row wrapper min-vh-100 flex-column flex-sm-row">
                <aside class="p-0 bg-dark flex-shrink-0">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark align-items-start flex-sm-column flex-row">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-fw"></i> Brand</a>
                        <a href class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sidebar">
                            <ul class="flex-column navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-fw"></i> <span class="">Link</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0 dropdown-toggle text-nowrap" href="#m1" data-parent="#navbar1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#m1" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="fa fa-address-card-o fa-fw"></i> <span class=""> Link</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="m1">
                                        <ul class="flex-column nav">
                                            <a class="nav-link px-0 text-truncate" href="#">Sub</a>
                                            <a class="nav-link px-0 text-truncate" href="#">Sub longer</a>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> <span class="">Link</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-fw"></i> <span class="">Link</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </aside>
                <main class="col bg-faded py-3">
                    <h2>Main</h2>
                    <p>Sriracha biodiesel taxidermy organic post-ironic, Intelligentsia salvia mustache 90's code editing brunch. Butcher polaroid VHS art party, hashtag Brooklyn deep v PBR narwhal sustainable mixtape swag wolf squid tote bag. Tote bag cronut semiotics, raw denim deep v taxidermy messenger bag. Tofu YOLO Etsy, direct trade ethical Odd Future jean shorts paleo. Forage Shoreditch tousled aesthetic irony, street art organic Bushwick artisan cliche semiotics ugh synth chillwave meditation. Shabby chic lomo plaid vinyl chambray Vice. Vice sustainable cardigan, Williamsburg master cleanse hella DIY 90's blog.</p>
                    <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies, forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>


<!-- your code -->







<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

remove these classes on the aside element `col-12 col-sm-2` and add a media query rule.